# how can I represent an array [100000][100000] storing only 0 or 1 in c++?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I tried:

```
vector<int <vector> > Graph(100000, vector<int> (100000)) ;
```

and

```
vector<bool<vector> >Graph  (100000,vector<bool> (100000)) ;
```

and

```
bool Graph [100000][100000] ;
```

... but none of them are working.

Comment: Do not add C tag for C++ questions!

Comment: Don't you think it's a little too big?

Comment: This is very unespecific *but it's not working*. Do you think we can guess what is wrong? Why it's not working is something essential when you ask a question. Because it would also reflect to what extent you understand the problem, it might be the case when you are trying to do something you are not ready to do yet.

Comment: Are you sure your computer has more than 37.25GiB of memory? (assuming `int` is 4-byte long)

Comment: Saving the vector as a file on your hard disk or SSD may be the solution. Implement cache system if needed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  Further context may help us see alternatives (sparse matrix, external storage, what have you).

Comment: I was solving one of the assignment in which the nodes can be upto 100000 and its a graph problem. thats why I asked this

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to create a vector of vector is:

```
vector<vector <int> > Graph(100000, vector<int> (100000));
```

However note that this array will take 10^5 * 10^5 * 4  = 40 billion bytes (assuming your int is 32 bits) or about 40 GB of RAM. You will have to  **have** that much memory of course.

Comment: Which special flags are you referring to?

Comment: I never needed any special flags to allocate that (and I have used several different compilers).  I don't even need that much ram+swap to allocate it.  Lots of the pages end up "demand-zero" when allocated and aren't used ram until you write some nonzeroes there.

Comment: @JSF , zenith. Alas I don't quite remember. I know that several(maybe 5 years) I needed a 10 GB vector for a problem I was solving for a competition. The compiler(or linker - I don't remember) printed some error and I only fixed it after adding some flags. I will remove this sentence as I don't have an example to back it up with.

Answer (score 1):

Well doing this

```
int wMyArray[100000][100000];
```

will give you this compile-time error:`error C2148: total size of array must not exceed 0x7fffffff bytes`

And then doing it with vector:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> wMyVector(100000, std::vector<int>(100000));

wMyVector.back().back();
```

Just takes forever to load, you can actually see the amount of working bytes increasing when it's loading.

Not sure you really want to do this.